# Generating list of unique values from two tables with all the columns from one table

Tags: sqlite

I don't normally post for help but I'm really stuck here as my SQL knowledge isn't great.

Here's what I want to do.
I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DistinctCategories (
name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
check INT);

CREATE TABLE Categories (
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
tid INTEGER NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
check INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I want to create a list of all possible category names for a specific tid. If a name is in both tables, I only want it listed once and that row will take on the "check" value in Categories.

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
Select *,
From Categories,
Where tid=2
```

Then adding a join here but I'm not sure how that would work.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Where is `tid` in the first table? Define 'possible names'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Left Outer Joins like this

```
Select C.id, C.tid, C.name, C.check
  from Categories as C LEFT JOIN DistinctCategories as DC
    ON C.name=DC.name
 where C.tid=2
```

I did not get which check you wanted to display and does c.check and dc.check have foreign key relation?

Comment: No foreign key relation. It is just a 0 or a 1. Wanting to display the  c.check. Thanks, I'll read up on outer joins and try this out.

Comment: so the above query should work for you, let me know about the progress

Comment: The solution did not work. This may have been because upon initialization Categories is empty. This led me to work out the following:
<pre><code>
Select *
From Categories as C
Where tid=2 AND check=1
LEFT JOIN  DistinctCategories as DC
ON C.name=DC.name
</code></pre>
I think this should work as check is always 0 in DC. Therefore it should only add the names in DC that aren't already in C right?
Problem is, I'm getting a syntax error near "LEFT" apparently. Not sure why just yet.

Comment: hey use table names infront of the attributes which confuses mostly like you have check in both tables so say C.check and C.tid(error on Left is because of this I guess) and you said " If a name is in both tables, I only want it listed once" so I thought c.name is enough for your query, okay if you do left join it will only give you the common values from dc, it skips the rest of the values that does not match in C. You should use union all for this, first see the output of left you will understand what happens exactly and then try other.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it lead me to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`UNION ALL`](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) and [`NOT IN`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op) operators:

```
SELECT name, check
  FROM Categories
 WHERE tid = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT name, check
  FROM DistinctCategories
 WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM Categories WHERE tid = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anyone would run into the same problem but my solution ended up being the following:

```
Select *
From Categories
Where tid=1
UNION
Select *
From Categories
Where Check=0 AND
NOT IN (Select Name
FROM Categories
Where tid=1)
Order By Name
```